# Multipeer Connectivity stores PeerID from previous sessions

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

```
func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    println(peerID) 

}
```

When I use this line of code, I receive peerIDs from previous sessions first, and then it gives the new peerIDs from the current session. Where is this data stored? Is there any way that I can remove the stored ones; maybe initialising somehow at the View Controller? I just want to get the peerID from the current session.

This is the console log:

```
<MCPeerID: 0x15559080 DisplayName = iphone>
<MCPeerID: 0x156616e0 DisplayName = iphooneeee>
<MCPeerID: 0x1563da30 DisplayName = iphooneeee>
```

Comment: Apparently, you should store the peerID once created and reuse it, instead of initialising a new peerID each time. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess... a session is a distributed object.  The framework (the OS) stores data for a session distributed across all devices participating in the session.  You might need to reboot all such devices to truly erase all data about the session.  I can't say how the framework knows when to erase a session that is stale or expired.  But for example, it could be keeping a session for a long time in case a device comes back in range.

Comment: any idea where to get more info about this?

Comment: I agree with C4 above, I'd love to find out how to clear the object.  As senty stated, the foundpeer returns bogus sessions.  As you stated, I rebooted the device and my issue was resolved.  NOT a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't sort out the storing issue but I found a way around by creating en empty array, initiating it to empty everytime I click on the button (which sorted out in my case), and saving the peerID in the array.

```
 ~ ViewController {
foundPeers: MCPeerID = []

~ ViewDidLoad {
  foundPeers = []

}

 @IBAction var button~ {
   foundPeers = []
} 

// and
  func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withDiscoveryInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

  foundPeers.append(peerID)

  foundPeers[foundPeers.count - 1].displayName
 }
}
```

Stored the data manually and